# One-wide swap red stone wires vertically?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have two wires running one above the other:

[image]

How can I "swap" them? So that, the input of the lower wire one is reflected in the output of the top wire and vice versa?

[image]

It can be any length and height but *must* be able to run alongside a duplicated version of itself.

It needs to work for at least 8 wires like this running in parallel, separated by 1-wide air gaps.

Comment: Are there only the two sets (4 redstone lines)  or are there more then two sets?

Comment: How compact does it need to be?

Comment: I think you could do a double inverter. I can't test it ATM though to be sure.

Comment: I have 8 wires running next to each other with a 1-wide air gap in-between.

Comment: Do you want to output two lines like this, but the top input redstone line leads into the bottom output line and vice versa?

Comment: @Fabian exactly

Comment: I have something, it's 3x3x3 and easy, but it's hard to explain. In about 20 hours I can answer. Edit: Oh, just saw the comment about how compact you need it. You should put that in the question. Also: Is the height a problem? 1 wide things tend to get really big in at least one other dimension.

Comment: @Fabian it is in the question. Height is not a problem

Comment: Well, that you have eight wires next to each other doesn't mean one module can't be wider than one block. For example two repeaters can be next to each other and the whole thing could shift to the side and then back again, as long as it doesn't interfere with the other lines.

Comment: @Fabian correct: "I can't come up with anything that doesn't interact with a duplicated version of itself two blocks to the side." Obviously I've already said this.

Comment: Are delays a problem? If repeaters are allowed, that makes it a lot easier.

Comment: @Fabian yeah they are allowed

Comment: I posted an answer. The reason why nobody else came up with anything (I'm not the biggest redstone expert) is probably that other people searched for solutions that are actually just one block wide. That might be possible, but it's way harder to do than necessary for your needs.

Comment: Now I'll try to find an actual one wide solution, but I doubt I'll find one.

Comment: You accepted my second answer now. Are you sure you want that? The first answer also works for your situation and it can send a signal on both lines at the same time. And it's faster.

Comment: @Fabian yeah you're right.I didn't read your answer thoroughly enough. Both being on is a very very common case and it's extremely important that this is handled properly. I'd rather not have any moving parts so I'll wait a while before maybe accepting your piston solution.

Comment: Because of lag? In that case you should go for the solution with the least redstone dust. Or to be more specific: The shortest redstone lines.

Comment: Four answers from me to a redstone question, each taking an hour or more to create (except for the dispenser solution, that was a quick thing). That was certainly the most amount of time I've put into answering a question on this site so far.

Comment: Does you new picture mean that it can be at most 5 blocks long and 5 blocks high? I think when you don't mind the output lines being at a different height than the input lines, it could be possible to create a solution that is only 5 blocks long.

Comment: @Fabian no, that picture's a bit misleading. It can be any length and height. I forgot to add that detail when I put the picture in the answer.

Comment: I keep coming back to this question. Now I have a solution that's actually 1 block wide, has the correct logic table and doesn't even break from spamming any or both inputs. It even has the potential to become truly 1 wide tileable. I'll try to do it without breaking all other properties.

Comment: Btw, what did you actually use this for?

Comment: In a computer's alu

Comment: Oh wow, I just found a video from 2012 that is very similar to one of my solutions! But it has moving parts, so it's nothing for you. And more importantly: It doesn't work anymore. For example it pushes a glass block under a redstone torch, which would make the torch pop off nowadays. Here's the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKliM-EBB8A

Comment: @ppperry not even close...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you apparently don't want moving parts (which eliminates solution 1 and 3) and being able to send a signal through both wires at the same time is a case that can happen (which eliminates solution 2), I worked out yet another solution.

Like the first one, it's 4 wide tileable for 2x2 wires. The idea to this is actually pretty similar to the first one, I just let the wires go around each other while avoiding that they power each other. The piston was an easy way to do that, since it can go down without going forward and only one redstone wire of the other path had to be replaced with a repeater to avoid problems. Without the piston, I had to use more repeaters and some clever wiring.

Here is a screenshot of all eight lines that you need:

[image]

Since that's not very helpful for rebuilding, you can download the structure file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1pVA4gNoJi3VzdrQWc1alNsb3c)*.

The odd numbered (counted from the left) columns have one redstone tick delay, the even numbered columns have three redstone ticks delay. I tried to switch one repeater over from the even numbered column to the odd numbered column, but that didn't work, because all three repeaters on the even column are there to avoid power overflow between the two lines of the even column. If the difference in delay is a problem, you can fix it by just putting two repeaters on first setting in front of the even numbered column lines.

It's 8 blocks long, 5 blocks high and of course 4 block wide for 2x2 wires, which makes it more compact than my first solution, but there are less air blocks, so you actually need a similar amount of material:

You need 28 redstone, 8 repeaters, 1 slab and 42 blocks that support redstone on it, some of them have to be solid, so you should build it all out of solid blocks to be sure, except for the one slab of course (that's not included in the 42 blocks).

This design works with pulses of any length.

Late edit: You can replace the repeater in the odd top input->odd bottom output line with a piece of redstone dust, but since that makes the delays even more varied, I won't edit that.

*That file is on my Google Drive, but it shouldn't get deleted. If I accidentally delete it, contact me (contact details on my profile page) saying that the file is in my October 2017 backup and link this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. It's not one wide, but it's four wide tileable for 2x2 redstone lines, since that's enough for what you need. It was a fun redstone challenge! My solution probably isn't the most compact one possible, but it's certainly more compact than my first attempt (that I won't show).

Here is a screenshot of all eight lines that you need:

[image]

Since that's not very helpful for rebuilding, you can download the structure file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1pVA4gNoJi3bWNTelQ2c0I3ZzA)*.

Every line has one redstone tick delay, the top input->bottom output line because of the piston and the bottom input->top output line because of a repeater.

It's 6 blocks long, 6 blocks high (for both lines together) and of course 4 blocks wide for two by two lines.

You need 28 redstone, 2 repeaters, 2 redstone blocks, 2 sticky pistons and 37 blocks that support redstone on it, most of them have to be solid, so you should build it all out of solid blocks to be sure.

A one redstone tick long pulse into the top input line makes the bottom output line stay permanently on because of maybe-bug-maybe-not-bug [MC-5726](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-5726). It fixes itself with the next pulse, no matter how long. You can prevent getting this situation if you put a repeater on second setting before this.

*That file is on my Google Drive, but it shouldn't get deleted. If I accidentally delete it, contact me (contact details on my profile page) saying that the file is in my October 2017 backup and link this answer.

Comment: I just now noticed that there are 10 lines in the screenshot, not 8. Whatever, it works the same for practically any even number (and even odd should work).

Answer (score 0):

I found an actual 1-wide solution. It still can't be put right next to itself, so it's not more compact than my first solution, but it fulfils the requirement that's in your title. And maybe it helps someone with very specific needs.

First I just built a design similar to what I first planned for the two-wide tileable design (that had one redstone line shared between both signals and used redstone signal strength to differentiate them afterwards), but I accidentally deleted it all with a `/fill` command. Oops. Well, as I tried to restore it piece by piece from memory and the little bits I had left, I had an idea. I had already used 1-wide `AND` gates for the design, so I built a completely different design combining three `NAND` gates and a bit of signal splitting to get them to swap.

This design has the disadvantage that you can't send a signal on both lines at the same time. If you try it, you just get no output on the other side. So instead of the desired logic table:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|IN 1 |IN 2 |OUT 1|OUT 2|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|false|false|false|false|
|false| true| true|false|
| true|false|false| true|
| true| true| true| true|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

you instead get this logic table:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|IN 1 |IN 2 |OUT 1|OUT 2|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|false|false|false|false|
|false| true| true|false|
| true|false|false| true|
| true| true|false|false|<-unwanted
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

But if you won't get that case ever, you can still use this. This happens because there is a part in the middle of the circuit that is used by both signals (it's off when any of the input signals is on). I just didn't find any other way to swap the signals in a 1-wide circuit.

Here is a screenshot of all eight lines that you need:
[image]
You can build it all from the screenshot, but if you want to load it into your own world, you can download the structure file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1pVA4gNoJi3LWlWNFhSS1RMTUk)*.

How it works: Both input signals split up into two lines (at the repeaters). The middle ones both go into one redstone torch, turning it off when any of the two input lines is on (`NAND` gate). At the same time, the signal travels further on the top/bottom. That then gets put through another `NAND` gate with the middle signal. The reason for that is that you want to turn the top lamp on when both the direct signal from the top input and the middle signal are off, because the middle signal is off when any of the inputs is on and the only case when both the middle and the top signal are off is when the bottom input is on and the top input off. The same applies to the top input and bottom output. At the end, the output lines just get raised up a bit to be at the same height as the input.

I could have made the green part of the circuit 1 block shorter by using a repeater at the end instead of only redstone dust, but that would just make it more expensive and slower just to save a little bit of space. That wasn't worth it in my opinion.

Every line has 4 redstone ticks delay. That's noticeably slower than my other design. (As I said, this one isn't as good, but it fulfils exactly the conditions from the title.)

It's 9 blocks long, 7 blocks high and of course 1 block wide.

You need 13 redstone, 6 repeaters, 3 redstone torches and 19 blocks that support redstone on it, some of them have to be solid, so you should build it all out of solid blocks to be sure.

A one redstone tick long pulse into any of the inputs just gets ignored. Any longer pulse into it works like expected and comes out at the end with the same length. You can prevent the signal getting ignored if you put a repeater on second setting before this.

*That file is on my Google Drive, but it shouldn't get deleted. If I accidentally delete it, contact me (contact details on my profile page) saying that the file is in my October 2017 backup and link this answer.

Answer (score 0):

And a third solution, this one isn't very useful, because you can only send a redstone signal every 61.5 seconds and the output stays on for that time.

There is actually a really easy way to make two signals cross: Through the air! What can go through the air? Arrows! It's even truly 1-wide and probably cheaper than my other answers, but if you have to send a signal at least once per minute, this isn't very useful.

Here is a screenshot of all eight lines that you need:

[image]

You can build it all from the screenshot, but if you want to load it into your own world, you can download the structure file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1pVA4gNoJi3LVJLN0pvbk5IV0E)*.

With 5 blocks long, 7 blocks high and 1 block wide, this is actually a pretty compact design. If it was of any use, that would be great! :D

You need 7 redstone, 1 wooden button, 1 wooden pressure plate, 2 dispensers, (preferably) 1152 arrows and 8 blocks that support redstone on it, this time it actually doesn't matter if you use full blocks or slabs.

Any input of any length leads to a 615 redstone tick output. Any new input in that time resets the countdown to 615 redstone ticks. At least it has no problem with 1 tick inputs, yay!

*That file is on my Google Drive, but it shouldn't get deleted. If I accidentally delete it, contact me (contact details on my profile page) saying that the file is in my October 2017 backup and link this answer.

Comment: This could be done with snowballs, hitting zombies on pressure plates and villagers to attract them back to make it much faster. But since you would have to fill up the dispensers regularly, it's still not a very useful circuit.

Comment: But now I have an idea: Maybe you could block the path to the villager. And you could do the same e.g. with cats and creepers. Or skeletons and dogs. Hm, maybe I'll write a sixth answer one day.

Answer (score 0):

A real 1 wide tileable solution that's actually useful (compared to my dispenser solution). The top->bottom line works as expected, but the bottom->top line can only send 1 tick pulses. If the top->bottom line is active and the bottom->top line gets activated, the top->bottom line gets deactivated for one tick due to [MC-123217](http://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-123217).

Here is a screenshot of all eight lines that you need:
[image]
You can build it all from the screenshot (the two pistons above each other are non-sticky, all other sticky), but if you want to load it into your own world, you can download the structure file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1InE2YIvQU_VIU4XwMGwZqqjpZWKpvdHU/view)*.

How it works: The top->bottom line just goes through like normal. But it goes through a vertical line of blocks on its way (third green column, counted from right to left), using a repeater. The bottom->top line makes a piston push up a column of four blocks, which lets the "signal" vertically cross the horizontal signal of the other line without interfering with it. When the top block arrives, it starts conducting the pre-made signal from the top redstone torch, which outputs the top signal and also makes the top piston push the row of blocks down again so that it's ready for the next use. Sadly it has to do that pretty quickly and can't wait for the bottom line to turn off, because the only signal it gets is the pushed up block and that can only be pushed back down from the top.
At the end a downwards sticky piston pushes down a redstone block so that the output lines are on the same height as the input lines. I can't just use redstone dust to go down, because then it wouldn't be tileable anymore.
Both lines have a delay of 5 ticks (counting only the green part).
Despite looking like it would break when spamming the inputs, it actually works, except for the mentioned case that the top input shortly gets cut off when the bottom input gets activated.

This circuit is 7 blocks long, 8 blocks high and of course 1 block wide.

You need 8 repeaters (one can be replaced with a solid block, but that reduces the timing to 4 ticks on one line), 3 redstone torches (one can be replaced with a redstone block), 2 normal and 3 sticky pistons, 2 redstone blocks and 17 solid blocks.

*That file is on my Google Drive, but it shouldn't get deleted. If I accidentally delete it, contact me (contact details on my profile page) saying that the file is in my March 2018 backup and link this answer.

Comment: The redstone blocks can be replaced with cauldrons with water in them, then one repeater per replaced redstone block has to be replaced with a comparator. Should give the same timing, but comparators are sometimes weird in that regard.